# How to use mocks with a test fixture in GMock?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a test fixture in my tests so I don't have to instantiate objects of my class repeatedly, but I'm not sure how to use mocks with it. To put it simply, this is how the class is defined:

```
class Class1 {
public:
  Class1(std::shared_ptr<Class2> class_two);
  void doThisThing() { doThatThing(); }
}

class Class2 {
public:
  Class2(Class3* class3_ptr);
  int doThatThing();
}
```

(class 1 is constructed using a shared pointer to class 2. Class 2 is constructed with a pointer to class 3. Class 1 calls on a function "doThisThing" which calls Class 2's function doThatThing.)

I need to create a mock for doThatThing() (and the rest of Class2's functions), but can't figure out how to pass the mock object to Class 1. Here is what I have so far in my testing code:

```
class TestClass1 : public ::testing::Test {
  TestClass1(){
//Construct instance of Class1 and store as member variable
    std::shared_ptr<Class3> class_three = std::make_shared<Class3>();
    std::shared_ptr<Class2> class_two = std::make_shared<Class2>((Class3*)class_three.get());
    class_one = new Class1(class_two);
  };
Class1* class_one;
}

MockClass2 : public Class2 {
  MOCK_METHOD0(doThatThing, int());
}

TEST_F(TestClass1, doThatThingTest){
  MockClass2 mockObj;

**THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK. How do I get that mockObj into my TestClass1 Fixture? As of now, it is calling the actual function, not the mock***

  class_one->doThatThing();
  EXPECT_CALL(mockObj, doThatThing());
}
```

I had to abstract and simplify the actual code, so I hope the above makes sense.

Comment: Google mock is no magic (alas!) and couldn't make something polymorphic when it is not like this originally. You need to use either virtual functions or templates in your original code in order to mock it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `MockClass2` works, you should try something like the following:

Here you should override the functions `SetUp` that is called right before every call of a test function to prepare your test data. And override `TearDown` that is called after every call of a test function to clean up test data.

```
struct TestClass1 : public ::testing::Test
{
    void SetUp() override
    {
        class_two_mock = std::make_shared<MockClass2>();
        class_one = std::make_unique<Class1>(class_two_mock);        
    }
    void TearDown() override
    {
        class_one.reset();
        class_two_mock.reset();
    }

    std::shared_ptr<MockClass2> class_two_mock
    std::unique_ptr<Class1> class_one;
};
```

In the test function you must declare your expectations before something is executed.

```
TEST_F(TestClass1, doThatThingTest)
{
    EXPECT_CALL(*class_two_mock, doThatThing());

    class_one->doThatThing();
}
```

You may need an interface for `Class2`. The code here is not tested.

Comment: Close.... but doesn't quite work. Since Class2 does not have a default constructor, MockClass2's default constructor is implicitly deleted which makes this line throw an error:
`class_two_mock = std::make_shared<MockClass2>();`

I tried adding MockClass2(){}; but received error that I need to explicitly initialize Class2.  Added
` Class3* class3_ptr = new Class3(); Class2(class3_ptr); `
and its saying "Redefinition of class3_ptr with a different type Class2 vs Class3*" ??

Comment: Yes, that is why I suggest to use an interface for `Class2`.

Comment: Is that the only option? I wanted to avoid having to edit the source code.

Comment: As Valeriy Savchenko mentioned in his comment that seems to be impossible.

Comment: BTW assuming your test is correct but fail, then you would not fix the classes/code? If so the test is needless.

Comment: I followed your recommendation by making an interface but am still encountering an issue... When I try to instantiate class_one using the mock object, I get an error that there is no matching constructor.

Comment: I think you should open a new question. There we can take a look to your new code.

Comment: Can I declare my expections in the Setup function?